# How do I produce <a href="/" id="logo"> with the link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All I want to produce is this HTML tag:

```
<a href="/" id="logo"></a>
```

I tried:

```
<%= link_to root_path, id: "logo" %>
```

But this produces:

```
<a href="/?id=logo">/</a>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to(root_path), id: "logo" %>
```

But that produces:

```
SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

The reason I am doing it like this is because I am including the logo via CSS....so that's why I haven't done a `link_to ... do` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<%= link_to "linky", "/", id: "logo" %>
```

If you don't want there to be a value you can just omit "linky" but leave the string declaration like:

```
<%= link_to "", "/", id: "logo" %>
```

This returns

```
<a id="logo" href="/">linky</a>
```

Comment: The 2nd statement is what I am looking for. I forgot the first argument to the method (i.e. setting the name to be `''`).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be:

```
<%= link_to '', root_path, :id => "logo" %>
```